# How to sort this json file with either jq or sed

Tags: sed, jq

```
{
  "adfdasfdafdfds": {
    "amount": 43,
    "mints": [
      "adfdasffd",
      "dsafdsafdsfds"
    ]
  },
  "dfsfsdfdsf": {
    "amount": 1020,
    "mints": [
      "dfsfsads"
    ]
  },
  "sdfsdfdfgf": {
    "amount": 1,
    "mints": [
      "fsfdsfdfds"
    ]
```

How to sort this code by amount in either jq or sed/awk ?

The problem is that the first part isn't defined.

Comment: Sort what? What is the goal here? What does a satisfactory solution look like?

Answer (score 2):

Json objects are inherently unordered so it doesn't make sense to sort one. However jq does treat it ordered so if you want to restructure this object so keys are ordered by some condition, you could do this:

```
to_entries | sort_by(.value.amount) | from_entries
```

Reread the object as a collection of key/value pairs, sort the pairs by what you want, then recreate the object.